# Setting svg fill attribute in Javascript

Tags: d3.js, svg, colors, fill

Beginner's question. Why does the color variable `color.svg` not work when I try to change my svg attribute? Everything else works: the other colors (for circles added later), as well as the size of the svg ([sizing taken from here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563)).

Constants:

```
// colors
var color = {svg: "black", 
             drop0: "rgba(204, 204, 255, 1)",
             drop1: "orange"};

// margins
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Now I make an svg and try set attributes.

```
// svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr({width: width + margin.left + margin.right,
          height: height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
          fill: color.svg})
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// followed by stuff about adding shapes, etc, which work
```

I would prefer not to set it in CSS. No errors are thrown on the browser. I've commented out everything but these lines, and the svg is still not colored black.

Comment: The CSS approach would be by setting `background-color`. However, if that's not an option then you can always create a rectangle with the same width and height of the svg to serve as your background and set the `fill` on it.

Comment: What do you expect setting the fill would do? Setting fill on an SVG wouldn't have an effect on the SVG's background. However, the fill setting *will* affect any svg graphic (eg circle, rect, path) contained within the SVG, if it doesn't have its own fill defined.

Comment: Gotcha! Okay, make a rectangle to serve as the background or do it shorter in CSS. Thanks, I was confused because svg has a fill attribute, and didn't realize that would apply only to other graphics contained in it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG's container has not attr "fill", instead it has "style". Just replace it like so:

```
var color = {
  svg: "black",
  drop0: "rgba(204, 204, 255, 1)",
  drop1: "orange"
};

// margins
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 10
};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//Now I make an svg and try set attributes.

// svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 900)
  .attr("height",600)
  .style("background-color", color.svg)  //  <---- HERE
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

[Here de jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3p8vasru/)

and check this: https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Answer (score 0):

@meetamit in comments helped me realize adding a fill on an SVG only affect svg graphics contained in the SVG. The SVG fill attribute does not change the color of the SVG. @JSBob offered two approaches: add a rect and set that fill, or set SVG's `background-color` in CSS.